# ObjectInputStream instance of

Tags: java, objectinputstream

I'm trying to read from a file I have saved using the following code:

```
    public void saveOnFile() {
    try {
        ObjectOutputStream output = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("object.txt"));
        output.writeObject(mediaList);
        output.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

    public void readFromFile() {
    try {
        ObjectInputStream inStream = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream("object.txt"));
        this.mediaList.add( (Media) inStream.readObject());
        inStream.close();
    } catch(Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

However, I don't know if `ObjectInputStream` knows what objects are inputted. Objects in this case can either be a "Movie" or a "TVShow" but the are all subclasses to Media.

I get the following errors:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to project.Media
at project.MediaHandler.readFromFile(MediaHandler.java:66)
at project.Window.<init>(Window.java:73)
at project.Window.main(Window.java:199)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Object that you wrote to the `ObjectOutputStream` is called `mediaList`, therefore I assume that this is an `ArrayList<Media>` rather than each individual `Media` object.
On the `ObjectInputStream`, you are reading an object and casting it to `Media`, but I think that you will find that it is an `ArrayList<Media>` (or however mediaList is defined when it is written to the `ObjectOutputStream`).

Comment: Yes i figured that much out and changed it to: 
this.mediaList.addAll( (ArrayList<Media>) inStream.readObject());
But this gives me Type safety: Unchecked cast from Object to ArrayList<Media>.
Thanks!

Comment: Right, how is mediaList defined when writing and reading? `ArrayList<Media>` or `ArrayList`, if it's the latter, then Java doesn't know what types are stored in the ArrayList and therefore assumes `ArrayList<Object>` when reading. So, you can read to `Object readObject`, and then check `if (readObject instancef ArrayList<Media>)` and cast  the `readObject` into `ArrayList<Media>`. It might not be elegant, but you can make that work.

Comment: Ended up going with a thrust method where i write the Arraylist out to a .txt via toString(); Then i just read it in variable by variable. But ObjectOutput-/Input-Stream is quite interesting so ill need to have a look at that in detail.

Comment: Yeah,ObjectInput/OutputStream can be a hassle at first, but once you've got them done, then there are much easier than "marshalling"/"unmarshalling" objects to strings.<br>
But obviously if you'd like to edit the file in which you store things, then you want a text (e.g. XML) file.

Comment: http://pastie.org/private/3oc1jt5uc0grnbgyskyvka i went this way, gives me full controll but as you say once i get the hang of it its a much easier method, especially if you have bigger objects to save.